# (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (WhatsAppBusinessPhoneNumber)

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to work with the WhatsApp business API, but When I try to send a message, always gives me this error with http code 400:

> "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (WhatsAppBusinessPhoneNumber)",

URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/NUMBER_ID/messages?access_token=**ACCESS_TOKEN**
```

Body:

```json
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "5**39&&&&&&1",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "hello_world",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (WhatsAppBusinessPhoneNumber)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "Ai8BDTgVwlWuJo6QeTmqRB7"
    }
}
```